# MPMediaPlayerController frame problem

Tags: iphone

Actually i want to play a video in a small area of self.view but initially or first time when the video play then video's visible area occupy this small part and other black area of video goes out of the boundary of this small area.
My code is

```
 -(void)animateVideoMPMediaPlayer:(NSString *)strVideoName{

    //self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton  = TRUE;

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strVideoName ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];

    NSURL *ur= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSLog(@"hello %@",ur);

    if(mediaPlayer)
        [mediaPlayer release];

    mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:ur];

    //mediaPlayer.fullscreen = YES; 

   //mediaPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    videoPlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;

    [mediaPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

    //[mediaPlayer setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];

    mediaPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(4,362,102 ,100);

    //mediaPlayer.view.bounds = CGRectMake(4,362,102 ,100);


    [self.view addSubview:mediaPlayer.view];

    mediaPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(4,362,102 ,100);

    [mediaPlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [mediaPlayer play];
    // [self performSelector:@selector(stopVideoPlease:) withObject:mediaPlayer afterDelay:5];


}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the scalingMode to Fill, try setting it to AspectFit and tell me if it still gets off the bound of the view.

Comment: sorry my mistake is that i am setting scaling mode of an another media player.